# How does scala slick determin which rows to update in this query

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I was asked how scala slick determines which rows need to update given this code

```
      def updateFromLegacy(criteria: CertificateGenerationState, fieldA: CertificateGenerationState, fieldB: Option[CertificateNotification]) = {
        val a: Query[CertificateStatuses, CertificateStatus, Seq] = CertificateStatuses.table.filter(status => status.certificateState === criteria)
        val b: Query[(Column[CertificateGenerationState], Column[Option[CertificateNotification]]), (CertificateGenerationState, Option[CertificateNotification]), Seq] = a.map(statusToUpdate => (statusToUpdate.certificateState, statusToUpdate.notification))
        val c: (CertificateGenerationState, Option[CertificateNotification]) = (fieldA, fieldB)
        b.update(c)
      }
```

**Above code is (as i see it)**

- a) looking for all rows that have "criteria" for "certificateState"
- b) a query for said columns is created
- c) a tuple with the values i want to update to is created

then the query is used to find rows where tuple needs to be applied.

**Background**

I wonder were slick keeps track of the Ids of the rows to update.

**What i would like to find out**

- What is happening behind the covers?
- What is Seq in "val a: Query[CertificateStatuses, CertificateStatus, Seq]"
- Can someone maybe point out the slick source where the moving parts are located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I reformatted your code a little bit to easier see it here and divided it into chunks. Let's go through this one by one:

```
    val a: Query[CertificateStatuses, CertificateStatus, Seq] = 
        CertificateStatuses.table
            .filter(status => status.certificateState === criteria)
```

Above is a query that translated roughly to something along these lines:

```
SELECT *  // Slick would list here all your columns but it's essiantially same thing
FROM certificate_statuses
WHERE certificate_state = $criteria
```

Below this query is mapped that is, there is a SQL projection applied to it:

```
    val b: Query[
        (Column[CertificateGenerationState], Column[Option[CertificateNotification]]), 
        (CertificateGenerationState, Option[CertificateNotification]), 
        Seq] = a.map(statusToUpdate =>
            (statusToUpdate.certificateState, statusToUpdate.notification))
```

So instead of `*` you will have this:

```
SELECT certificate_status, notification
FROM certificate_statuses
WHERE certificate_state = $criteria
```

And last part is reusing this constructed query to perform update:

```
    val c: (CertificateGenerationState, Option[CertificateNotification]) = 
        (fieldA, fieldB)

    b.update(c)
```

Translates to:

```
UPDATE certificate_statuses
SET certificate_status = $fieldA, notification = $fieldB
WHERE certificate_state = $criteria
```

I understand that last step may be a little bit less straightforward then others but that's essentially how you do updates with Slick ([here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#updating) - although it's in monadic version).

As for your questions:

> What is happening behind the covers?

This is actually outside of my area of expertise. That being said it's relatively straightforward piece of code and I guess that an update transformation may be of some interest. I provided you a link to relevant piece of `Slick` sources at the end of this answer.

> What is Seq in "val a:Query[CertificateStatuses, CertificateStatus, Seq]"

It's collection type. Query specifies 3 type parameters:

- `mixed type` - Slick representation of table (or column - `Rep`)
- `unpacked type` - type you get after executing query
- `collection type` - collection type were above `unpacked type`s are placed for you as a result of a query.

So to have an example:

- `CertificateStatuses` - this is your Slick table definition
- `CertificateStatus` this is your case class
- `Seq` - this is how your results would be retrieved (it would be `Seq[CertificateStatus]` basically)

I have it explained here: http://slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/47 (and 3 next slides or so)

> Can someone maybe point out the slick source where the moving parts are located?

I think this part may be of interest - it shows how query is converted in update statement: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/51e14f2756ed29b8c92a24b0ae24f2acd0b85c6f/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcActionComponent.scala#L320

**It may be also worth to emphasize this:**

> I wonder were slick keeps track of the Ids of the rows to update.

**It doesn't.** Look at generated SQLs. You may see them by adding following configuration to your logging (but you also have them in this answer):

`<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG" />`

(I assumed `logback` above).